# How to make Custom Dialog immovable in InstallScript?

Tags: installshield, customdialog, installscript-msi

I have a basic MSI project. In this project I have created one custom dialog (because of requirement) using InstallScript code. I want to make that Custom Dialog immovable. How can I achieve this in InstallScript code? Can we use `DialogSetInfo()` to achieve this?